# Creating icons in application activity and making them transparent

Tags: android, icons, transparency

I want to create icons as something like [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TPOk6.jpg)  or something like on the homepage of quickr. If I use custom gridview for this [as in this](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-gridview-example/) (of course in my case I need the text below the image ), then adding listeners to that would be difficult I guess. Should I use buttons for that with the image and text below that provided the background is transparent? If so which layout I need to use? Or is there any icon view facility in android like other views such as button and imageviews, so that we can modify as per our requirement.

Answer (score 1):

You should use button for that.

```
<Button
  android:id="@+id/btnIconName"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:drawableTop="@drawable/iconimage"
  android:text="IconTitle" />
```

For showing icon you should use android:drawableTop and for iocnTitle use  android:text
Property.

I hope my answer is helpful to you.

Comment: Thanks, I will try it and let you know. +1 for your response

Answer (score 0):

GridView will be the best option to do this and why dont you ask your graphics guy to add text with image.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I too thought that and mentioned in my question. But adding listeners to the custom gridview elements? Graphics guy? There is no one here who even have knowledge on Android. Everything I have to do.

Comment: You can add listeners to the custom gridview, some months ago i did this and worked very well, try to find example on drag and drop in android gridview.